# What options do you have on creating a server in Quake Live?

Tags: quake-live, server-administration

So since Quake Live left beta status. As a "pro user" you are able to create a server on your own.

What options do you have?

Are there options like: "Only Clan-mates may join" or "Only players from my friendlist may join"

And is the server only active while the creator is ingame?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out from a Forum:

- Match Location (only vicinity not country, as far I know)
- Match Visibility
- Match Password
- Instagib Mode
- Spawn Protection (yes/no)
- Game Type
- Arena
- You can invite friends

You can NOT change player slots - this is awkward :(
edit: meanwhile there is a vote option to adjust the team size

Please correct me, if something changes (as long as I don't have a pro-account).

Comment: It's basically the practice game setup screen.

Answer (score 1):

There are several new features for pro-subscribers only, apart from the standard options.

One of the most important is the ability to create a PQL server, which is something Q3 CPMA-like. You can invite up to three standard-user friends, and the server doesn't need the creator to be alive, it just dies 15 minutes after the last person leaves it. The creator must be in the server, though, for the other players to join in.

Answer (score 0):

Pro account holders can also invite non premium/pro accounts (e.g. standard free accounts) to join the created server as well.

Answer (score 0):

eL13 is right about the options.

As for the server being active, you can leave it on for however long you want. Just leave yourself in spectator mode. I was one of the first one's to get a pro account, so I would leave it on in public mode when me and my friends weren't playing just so that others on my friends list could enjoy it.